# How to reset Messenger password without knowing it on account that has two-stage verification?

Tags: facebook

I'm doing the following stuff on my iPhone, that's the only device when I'm logged in.

**How can I reset my Messenger account password without knowing it, especially on an account that has two-stage verification?**

When I navigate to Messenger > Settings > See more in Account Center > Password and Security > Change Password > [My Name],

I encounter a pop-up where I can change the password using the old password, which I don't remember. So, I click on "Forgotten your password?" and it shows me a pop-up with the message: "Try typing the password again:" (it might sound different, but I use Messenger in Polish). The only buttons I see are "Log in" (which would only work if I know the password) and "It's not my account."

How can I change it? Is there any way to do that?

Comment: are you talking about the "messages.app" on the iPhone or Facebook Messenger or something else. If the former Messages.app is tied to (and uses) your AppleID.